# Worker threads, jobs which have a particular "colour", only one job of each colour must be running, what synchronization primitive do I need?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have N worker threads, and a queue of jobs.  When a worker thread is idle, it picks a job from the queue and starts running it.  So far, so easy.

However my jobs have a property which I'll call "colour".  Two jobs of the same colour must never be running at the same time.

For example, say there are 2 threads, one is running a red job, and the other is idle.  The idle thread looks at the queue, but it must not pick a red job (since if it did there would be two red jobs running which is not allowed).  If there's, say, a blue job in the queue, it could run it.  If there are only red jobs in the queue, then the idle thread must wait until the other thread finishes.  Then both threads are idle and they must pick differently coloured jobs to run, and if by that time there are still only red jobs in the queue, one would have to stay idle.

My question is what synchronization primitives I should use here.  I thought about grouping the queue into colours, and I can attach a mutex to each colour group, but then I'm stuck on how to use those mutexes.  (The actual program is written in OCaml using pthreads so it has access to the usual pthread primitives and ones built on top of pthreads).

This sounds like a rather unusual case, but it's related to a real world problem: I'm writing a dependency runner (think: "make").  It must never run two recipes ("jobs") in parallel if both recipes target the same output file ("colour").

Comment: Please edit your post. Please clarify, by adding in your question, that you are writing a C application (if it is the case, otherwise please explicitly indicate your programming language) with POSIX threads (pthreads). There is no indication of that in the text, and we have to guess that from the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few "obvious" solutions.

1. You could have a "red" thread and a "blue" thread, servicing separate "red" and "blue" queues. Since you never want to have more than one "red" job in progress, having a thread pool doesn't buy you anything.
2. If for some reason you still want to multiplex "red" jobs on a thread pool, you could still use separate "red" and "blue" queues, and a boolean flag indicating whether corresponding color job is in progress. An idle thread will then iterate over all non-empty queues and pick the first one that has `in_progress == false`.
3. You could have a single queue combined with a set of boolean flags. Now idle thread will iterate over the queue until it finds a job for which `in_progress[color] == false` and pick that.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what synchronization primitives I should use here.

There is a variety of synchronization objects you could use to protect the queue and any other shared objects against data races.  Mutexes and semaphores are prominent among these, but there are others, too.

However, since one of the possibilities is that a thread must suspend operation until a condition is satisfied (a task of a new colour becomes available, or a task is completed) you need a condition variable.  Condition variables are necessarily used together with mutexes, with the natural idiom being that the mutex protects (at least) the shared data that must be accessed to evaluate the condition.  Thus, "one mutex and one condition variable" is a good answer to the question posed.

But you seem also uncertain about how to structure the queue and how to use the synchronization primitives.  That is specific to your particular project, but it is possible to make some general observations and suggestions.  Your explanation of the real-world case suggests that colour values are essentially arbitrary, as opposed to being drawn from a small, fixed vocabulary.  This rules out dedicating a separate thread to each colour, putting you instead in the situation where at any given time, every idle thread is viable for running each task that is eligible to run.

Schematically, then, every worker thread would do something like this:

1. **Lock the mutex**.
2. If no enqueued task is eligible to run, then

   a. **Wait on the condition variable**.

   b. When the thread returns from the wait, go back to (2).
3. (If control reaches this point then there is an eligible task on the queue.) Dequeue an eligible task, *T*, of color *C*(*T*).
4. Update colour-tracking data to show that a task of colour *C*(*T*) is running.
5. **Unlock the mutex**.
6. Run task *T*.
7. **Lock the mutex**.
8. Update colour-tracking data to show that there is no longer a task of colour *C*(*T*) running.
9. **Broadcast to the condition variable**.
10. Go back to (2).

I presume you will want to include a termination condition to allow your threads to exit cleanly.  That would probably be evaluated as part of step (2).  Make sure that after breaking out of the loop, threads **unlock the mutex**.

Note also that a thread that wants to enqueue a new task while the workers are running -- whether a worker thread itself or some other -- must hold the mutex while doing so, and should broadcast to the CV after doing so.

> I thought about grouping the queue into colours, and I can attach a mutex to each colour group, but then I'm stuck on how to use those mutexes.

Indeed.  A mutex per group does not help, because only one mutex can be associated with the CV.  That mutex must be held while a thread is evaluating whether the condition for proceeding is satisfied, and while a thread is updating any of the data involved in evaluating that condition.  Additional mutexes protecting subsets of that data would be unhelpful, because there could never be more than one thread contending for them (the one holding the main mutex).

It might still be reasonable to add structure to your queue to facilitate the evaluation of which tasks are eligible to run, but you haven't given us enough information to suggest details.  (And the question is already plenty broad, so please do not expand it with any such information.)